Page is not refreshning in related list but it is refreshing in full screen
I using Lightning-Upload to upload the file and once it is uploaded i want to refresh the screen and show the toast message but when file is uploaded refresh is happening in full screen but when i add this functionality in related list refresh is not happening
<template>
        <lightning-file-upload
            label=""
            name="fileUploader"
            accept={acceptedFormats}
            record-id={recordId}
            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
            multiple>
    </lightning-file-upload>
</template>

import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { RefreshEvent } from "lightning/refresh";
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class UploadFunctionalityInAttachments extends NavigationMixin (LightningElement ){
    @api recordId;
    @track isLoading=false;
    @track uploadedFiles = [];
    get acceptedFormats() {
        return ['.pdf', '.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.xlsx','.xls','.csv','.doc','.docx','.zip','.mp3','.mp4','.avi','.svg','.gif','.wav','.ppt','pptx'];
    }
    handleUploadFinished(event) {
        const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
        console.log(uploadedFiles);
       
        let uploadedFileNames = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
            uploadedFileNames += uploadedFiles[i].name + ', ';
        }

        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: uploadedFiles.length + ' Files uploaded Successfully: ' + uploadedFileNames,
                variant: 'success',
            }),
        );

        this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
        console.log('Before refreshing view...');
        eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
        console.log('After refreshing view.');      
        
    }
   

}

i tried to refresh the page using refresh event it is not working to me but i tried to refresh using  eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
but force:refreshView is working but it is only on full screen not working on related list
